# Htaccess Does not allow third rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two rules in my htaccess file and while the first two are working I can't figure out why the third one isn't.
What I have currently is

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?key=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?key=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?key=$1&id=$2&user=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?key=$1&id=$2&user=$3


<files config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
<files loader.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

I can go to `localhost/page/5` and I can go to `localhost/page` just fine, but if I try to go to `localhost/module/5/1` it breaks and throws me a 404 error.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I don't see anything, so it could be a simple yet stupid typo on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your rule regex are matching `/module/5/1` URI. Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?key=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?key=$1&id=$2&user=$3 [L,QSA]
```

`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`